# unable to install python-devel package in fedora

Tags: python, fedora, rpm

i was trying to install psycopg using pip and ran into this error

> In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:0:
>   ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>    #include

I understand python-devel package is missing and when i tried to install, its shows

> Error: nothing provides python-rpm-macros needed by python-devel-2.7.12-6.fc24.i686

How could i resolve the issues with python-rpm-macros??

Thank you

Comment: isn't `python-rpm-macros` some `rpm` package which you have to install ? http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/python-rpm-macros

Comment: i am looking for it ...let me check. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @furas i tried it. Now it is asking for other rpm packages..so i think it will resolve the issue... (stupid i didnt notice it) :-)

Comment: Please expose your command line of how you do install packages in Fedora. Definitely you're doing it wrong (or got _very_ broken OS config)

Comment: `sudo dnf install python-devel` is your remedy

Comment: @agg3l ..i had some issues with OS config... I got it working ..
I downloaded the packages for [link]https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python2-rpm-macros&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=

Comment: @agg3l as i said in the question , `sudo dnf install python-devel`  didnt works since the rpm is missing...

Comment: @furas can you please close the question giving your answer of missing rpm

Comment: have you tried `dnf reposync` for example? This question seems to be forwarded to superuser to help you to fix your Fedora box. Everything is there for correct repositories setup

Comment: @agg3l `reposync` was a good idea....i can see a hell lot of issues now!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python-rpm-macros` can be some rpm package which you have to install.

I found this: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/python-rpm-macros